# django-simple-history is storing changes twice

Tags: django, django-simple-history

I tried django-simple-history and I discovered that every create or update is stored twice in the history model. I don't know which information is now useful for you to help me, but I use CBV's and model forms. I followed the instructions on how to install and setup and everything works fine. What I'm wondering is why there is a command line called clean_duplicate_history, which indeed removes all duplicates records. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4):

`django-simple-history` is naive. It works by creating a new simple history record on a `post_save` signal. Thus, it creates a new record every time you `.save` regardless of whether anything has changed. Because of that, duplicate records may increase significantly, which is why there is a `clean_duplicate_history` utility method. If the same record is being store twice and you're unsure why, it's likely that you're making multiple saves.

Comment: Thank your for the answer. This was what I thought first also, but I do not find the double save call... It is on all models where I use simple-history. Have to look deeper in my code ;)